# How do I get a channel layer from Django-Channels lib to communicate with Redis in Oracle VM using Docker Toolbox?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, python, django, redis

I am using Django Channels and am trying to make sure that a channel layer can communicate with Redis. However, I have Windows 10 Home edition which means I had to use Docker Toolbox to create an Oracle VM Virtualbox so I can run Redis in a Linux environment. My Django project has its own virtualenv on the desktop while Redis is running on the Docker Toolbox. I am following the django-channels tutorial exactly: https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part_2.html

Initially, I ran `$ docker run -p 6379:6379 -d redis:2.8` and this didn't do anything but created the docker image for me. However, I ran

> $ docker run -p 6379:6379 redis:2.8

and this started up the port which is great. Not sure if this has anything to do with it, I received the following responses prior to the redis-server being able to accept connections on port 6379:

```
[1] 08 Aug 21:12:19.210 # Server started, Redis version 2.8.23
[1] 08 Aug 21:12:19.211 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
[1] 08 Aug 21:12:19.211 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.
[1] 08 Aug 21:12:19.212 * The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6379
```

The next part I ran the following as per the tutorial:

```
$ python3 manage.py shell
>>> import channels.layers
>>> channel_layer = channels.layers.get_channel_layer()
>>> from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
>>> async_to_sync(channel_layer.send)('test_channel', {'type': 'hello'})
```

and I received this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\wtran\venv\chattaboutit\lib\site-packages\asgiref\sync.py", line 110, in __call__
    return call_result.result()
  File "C:\Users\wtran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 425, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "C:\Users\wtran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\Users\wtran\venv\chattaboutit\lib\site-packages\asgiref\sync.py", line 142, in main_wrap
    result = await self.awaitable(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\wtran\venv\chattaboutit\lib\site-packages\channels_redis\core.py", line 293, in send
    async with self.connection(index) as connection:
  File "C:\Users\wtran\venv\chattaboutit\lib\site-packages\channels_redis\core.py", line 820, in __aenter__
    self.conn = await self.pool.pop()
  File "C:\Users\wtran\venv\chattaboutit\lib\site-packages\channels_redis\core.py", line 70, in pop
    conns.append(await aioredis.create_redis(**self.host, loop=loop))
  File "C:\Users\wtran\venv\chattaboutit\lib\site-packages\aioredis\commands\__init__.py", line 178, in create_redis
    loop=loop)
  File "C:\Users\wtran\venv\chattaboutit\lib\site-packages\aioredis\connection.py", line 108, in create_connection
    timeout, loop=loop)
  File "C:\Users\wtran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 339, in wait_for
    return (yield from fut)
  File "C:\Users\wtran\venv\chattaboutit\lib\site-packages\aioredis\stream.py", line 19, in open_connection
    lambda: protocol, host, port, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\wtran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 778, in create_connection
    raise exceptions[0]
  File "C:\Users\wtran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 765, in create_connection
    yield from self.sock_connect(sock, address)
  File "C:\Users\wtran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\asyncio\selector_events.py", line 450, in sock_connect
    return (yield from fut)
  File "C:\Users\wtran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\asyncio\selector_events.py", line 480, in _sock_connect_cb
    raise OSError(err, 'Connect call failed %s' % (address,))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 10061] Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 6379)
```

Just want to acknowledge that I did set up the following on settings.py:

```
# mysite/settings.py
# Channels
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.routing.application'
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [('127.0.0.1', 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

Is this because my project is not in the same VM container where Redis resides? I would think this wouldn't matter since it is its' own server where I am trying to communicate with localhost.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely, due to the way that Docker Toolbox works (had the same problem).

Docker Toolbox uses VirtualBox as virtualization solution, which creates its own virtual network device with its own IP.

**Solutions**:

1. Hardcode the IP belonging to the docker container, as shown after `Docker Quickstart Terminal` did boot.

```
                        ##         .
                  ## ## ##        ==
               ## ## ## ## ##    ===
           /"""""""""""""""""\___/ ===
      ~~~ {~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~ /  ===- ~~~
           \______ o           __/
             \    \         __/
              \____\_______/

docker is configured to use the default machine with IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
For help getting started, check out the docs at https://docs.docker.com


Start interactive shell
$
```

2. Extract the IP from the environment variable `DOCKER_HOST`, i.e. like this:

```
import os
import re

def get_docker_ip():
    docker_host = os.environ.get("DOCKER_HOST", "127.0.0.1")
    docker_ip = re.search(r"(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})", docker_host)
    return docker_ip.group(1)
```

3. Use [`Docker Desktop for Windows`](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/) with Hyper-v (Microsofts virtualization solution), since it binds to localhost.

   Note that using Hyper-v will break VirtualBox, since they don't play nicely together.

   If you still want to use both, you need do de-/activate Hyper-v and reboot depending on what you want to use, as described in [this guide](https://derekgusoff.wordpress.com/2012/09/05/run-hyper-v-and-virtualbox-on-the-same-machine/).

Comment: Thanks for your response. So I am Solution 1, when you mention setting the environment variables, did you mean DOCKER_HOST = tcp://192.xxx.xx.xxx:2376. It seems that there is a couple of environment variables that gets set up automatically once the default virtual network device was created. Also would I have to do Solution 2. to deactivate Hyper-V?? The thing about Hyper-V is that I read Windows 10 Home doesn't support Hyper-V but I have seen an uncheck box for Hyper-V Extensible Virtual Switch, when I right click into properties of virtualbox.

Comment: Meant to say *going with Solution 1

Answer (score 0):

I hard-coded the IP as suggested below and it worked. Add the IP in the settings CHANNEL_LAYERS configuration.

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
'default': {
    'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
    'CONFIG': {
        'hosts': [('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', 6379)],
    },
},
```

}

Thanks a lot.
Adrian